# How do constants work in Go?

Tags: go

In Go which snippet allocates less objects? Or do they both use the same amount of allocations, if so; why? (:

```
for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        log.println("hello")
    }
```

Does the code below allocates only 1 string?

```
const (
    HELLO string = "hello"
)

for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
    log.println(HELLO)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler will inline the string and not allocate it X number of times. If a language did that, I would not use it.

Comment: Compare the assembly outputs of both examples with `go tool compile -S`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of your program that prints out the underlying string representation in both cases.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    Hello string = "hello"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        a := "hello"
        sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
        fmt.Println(a, " ", *sh)
    }

    fmt.Println()

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        a := Hello
        sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
        fmt.Println(a, " ", *sh)
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
hello   {4870353 5}
hello   {4870353 5}
hello   {4870353 5}

hello   {4870353 5}
hello   {4870353 5}
hello   {4870353 5}
```

The string header in `{}` in the output shows a pointer to the character data ("hello"), and the length of the string.

You can see that the pointer to the string data is the same throughout the program: the bytes data "hello" is referenced at exactly one memory address (here 4870353), no matter the loop count, and no matter whether it's a hardcoded string or a constant.

The language spec itself makes no guarantees about such behavior, but constant string interning is such a natural optimisation that it would be surprising if go behaved in any significantly different way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find whether Go makes some allocations or not is writing the benchmark. In your case code might look like:

```
package sof

import "log"

const (
    HELLO = "hello"
)

func forString(max int) {
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        logMsg("hello", false)
    }
}

func forConst(max int) {
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        logMsg(HELLO, false)
    }
}

func logMsg(msg string, stdOut bool) {
    if stdOut {
        log.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

And benchmark:

```
package sof

import "testing"

func BenchmarkForString(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        forString(i)
    }
}

func BenchmarkForConst(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        forConst(i)
    }
}
```

Then you can just run the benchmark:

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem
```

Very important is -benchmem flag. Without it your benchmark tells you only about the benchmark time - you don't get info about number of allocations and average size of allocation per operation.

Output of the benchmark:

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
BenchmarkForString-4      100000        133551 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkForConst-4       100000        128585 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      .../sof 26.475s
```

In last 2 columns you have an information about the size of allocations and its number. In your example there are only zeros which means that both funcs don't make any allocations : )